# How to reactivate ribbons in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have bought an excel "program" (sheet) that uses macros. It disables all default excel ribbons and replace them with its own.

Unfortunately I have to sign the macros with my own certificate so I can get them to work on our Systems with restricted macro security. There for I need to get the developer ribbon. But how can I enable it?  The excel program seems to block all options.

Comment: Disable macros and then open the Excel file?

Comment: Which Excel version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem: Just press alt + f11

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Excel in safe mode. Hold the CTRL key while opening the file.